# Why isn't my UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition working?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, transition

I made a custom `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` for the dismissal of my detail view controller as so:

```
class DismissAnimator : NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.4
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

        guard let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to)?.childViewControllers.first as? MainController,
            let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from) as? DetailViewController
            else {
                return
        }
        containerView.insertSubview(toVC.view, belowSubview: fromVC.view)
        fromVC.view.isHidden = true

        let snapshot = fromVC.view.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)
        containerView.insertSubview(snapshot!, aboveSubview: toVC.view)

        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext),
            animations: {
                snapshot!.center.y += UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        },
            completion: { _ in
                fromVC.view.isHidden = false
                snapshot?.removeFromSuperview()
                transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
        })
    }
}
```

My `MainViewController` has the following functions:

```
extension MainController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "openDetailView" {
        let cell = sender as! PopularCell
        let indexPath = popularCollectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
        let destinationViewController = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
        destinationViewController.transitioningDelegate = self
        destinationViewController.event = events[indexPath!.row]
        destinationViewController.interactor = interactor
    }
}

func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return OpeningAnimator()
}

func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return DismissAnimator()
}

func interactionControllerForDismissal(using animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
    return interactor.hasStarted ? interactor : nil
}
```

and this is how my pan interaction is being handled:

```
@IBAction func handleGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let percentThreshold:CGFloat = 0.3
        let translation = sender.translation(in: view)
        let progress = progressAlongAxis(pointOnAxis: translation.y, axisLength: view.bounds.height)

    guard let interactor = interactor,
        let originView = sender.view else { return }

    switch originView {
    case view:
        break
    case tableView:
        if tableView.contentOffset.y > 0 {
            return
        }
    default:
        break
    }

    switch sender.state {
    case .began:
        interactor.hasStarted = true
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    case .changed:
        interactor.shouldFinish = progress > percentThreshold
        interactor.update(progress)
    case .cancelled:
        interactor.hasStarted = false
        interactor.cancel()
    case .ended:
        interactor.hasStarted = false
        interactor.shouldFinish
            ? interactor.finish()
            : interactor.cancel()
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, as soon as I barely drag the modal view controller, it disappears automatically, with no interactivity. Putting a breakpoint in the `handleGesture(sender:)` shows that the function is being called so I'm confused as to what I should do now.

Any help?

Comment: Debug your progress value at first. You might make a mistake with sigh or smt else in progress calculation. Also, does your animation works properly without interactivity?

Comment: @O.G.O yup everything works perfectly without interactivity and I don't think it's the progress calculation, the same code works for another animation in another project but not this one

Comment: If so, there is not enough information for me to help you. Can you provide github link to the project?